# How to allow user to specify currency format in Swift

Tags: swift, localization

I'm curious, does anyone have suggestions on how to give users control over the conversion of Double/Float to a currency value using the `formatted` methods introduced in [WWDC21 What's new in Foundation video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10109/?time=1545)?

Here's the code snippet from the video:

```swift
    let price = 29
    let priceFormatted = price.formatted(.currency(code: "usd"))
    // priceFormatted is "$29.00"
    print(priceFormatted)
```

I would like to give the user an interface that lets them choose between a default that the OS supplies based on device settings, and choosing something specific (eg Japanese Yen). So I guess that boils down to two things:

1. What is the list of codes that the `.currency(code:)` method can take? I’d also like it if there was some API that gave me a mapping from codes (eg “usd”) to localized label I can present the user (eg “U.S. Dollars” in English).
2. How do I ask the OS for the code that would be the default for the locale settings?

Comment: See `Locale.Currency.isoCurrencies` and `Locale.localizedString(forCurrencyCode:)`.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for (along with `Locale.current.currency?.identifier` for part 2). Would you like to write it up as an Answer to be accepted? If you don't have time to do so, let me know and I will do so.

Comment: @HangarRash yes, please write it up as an answer. It will be more helpful to other people searching for the answer to the same question.

Comment: @CuriousJorge if HangerRash doesn't want to write it up, you can answer the question yourself and then accept it.

Comment: Been traveling all day. No time to type up a real answer. Glad someone else did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localised currency information is encapsulated by the [Currency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/currency) structure in Foundation.

A list of the standard currencies (conforming to [ISO 4217](https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html)) can be accessed using [`Locale.Currency.isoCurrencies`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/currency/3952317-isocurrencies). But as that list is probably too exhaustive, you might prefer to use [`Locale.commonISOCurrencyCodes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293073-commonisocurrencycodes) which has roughly half the entries (156 vs 304 at this time).

You can get a localised label for each code using the [`localizedString(forCurrencyCode:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293551-localizedstring) method on a given `Locale`.

Finally, you can get the default currency code for your device's settings using:

```swift
 let defaultCurrencyCode = Locale.current.currency?.identifier
```

Kudos to @HangarRash for his quick response!